# Função Back para voltar atrás num dispositivo Android do Perfecto Lab

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cucumber

Boa tarde Comunidade,

Estou a usar o Cucumber no Eclipse para elaborar testes automatizados numa aplicação instalada num Android que está numa VM, nomeadamente, alojada no site Perfecto Lab. A Perfecto Lab têm várias funções que conseguimos chamar no eclipse, por exemplo, voltar ao homescreen, fazer swipe, entre outras. Uma função que considero importante que não existe, é a função para clicar no botão Back do Android. Os testes são efectuados em cucumber, mas as funções são criadas em java. Estou também a trabalhar com appium, caso seja relevante para a resolução do meu problema.

Este é o código correspondente ao teste a efectuar. Abre a aplicação, clica num botão e no fim, clicaria no botão back do android para voltar atrás.

```
@MyAxa_Spain_Login
Feature: Customer without car contracts tries to consult his car contracts

@Start_app_and_Login
Scenario: launch APP
    Given I start application by name "My AXA España" 
    Then I click on "button.aceder"
    And wait until "button.username" to be visible
    And I wait for "5" seconds
    Then I Click Back
```

Esta é a minha função que estou a tentar implementar para clicar no botão back do android.

```
@QAFTestStepProvider
public class BackKey {

    @Then("^I Click Back")  
    public void clickBack() {

        //AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
        AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

        PerfectoDeviceSteps getSteps = new PerfectoDeviceSteps();

        String host = "https://atc.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub";
        //PerfectoDeviceSteps getSteps = new PerfectoDeviceSteps();

        //getSteps.goToHomeScreen();

        try {
            //DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("", "", Platform.ANY);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("user", "mailfake@fakemail.com");
            capabilities.setCapability("password", "passfake");
            //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "CE12160C43D92A0704");
            driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(host), capabilities);
            //((AndroidDeviceActionShortcuts) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
            ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>) driver).pressKeyCode(4);
            System.out.println("chega aqui");
            getSteps.takeScreenshot();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

O que está a acontecer quando tento correr o teste, ele efectua todos os passos sem erros, o problema é que não está a voltar atrás. O código tem linhas comentadas, para vocês verem o que já testei.
Tenho a sensação que estou no caminho certo, não sei se estou a inicializar mal a variável.

O objectivo era colocar a função do botão back a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Ivo,

Não tem muito segredo, mas acredito que você precise separar as responsabilidades.

No seu código você está usando o capabilities como orquestrador dos seus testes, ele deveria somente setar os capabilities e nada mais, você poderia ter uma classe onde criaria os métodos utilizando JUNIT.

Mas para responder sua pergunta a forma certa para tocar no botão back do android é :

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

Onde O Driver é uma instância do Appium e pressKeyCode é o método disponível nessa instância.

Corrigindo o que você colocou deveria estar assim o seu step_definiton:

```
@QAFTestStepProvider
public class BackKey {

@Then("^I Click Back")
public void clickBack() {

AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

try {

  driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
  getSteps.takeScreenshot();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```